# Footer actions in separate file

Tags: java, android, footer

I've create a footer.xml which contains my footer layout and I've include this one in my main.xml.

Now I want to separate my java code in two files but I don't know how to put my Footer actions in Footer.java and how I include this file into MainActivity.java ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a class that extend Activity... like FooterActivity and there implement all you need for footer, after that your mainactivity should extend from FooterActivity and not from Activity.

Comment: Yeah ! It works (I have juste rename my file as RootActivity and I'll put my header methods in this one too).